# man pages have odd characters in the output

Tags: linux, man

I am using Fedora and Gnome. I use GNOME Terminal and I am experiencing some odd output characters which seem to surround certain keywords on output.

```
1mNAME0m
       sync - Synchronize cached writes to persistent storage

1mSYNOPSIS0m
       1msync 22m[4mOPTION24m] [4mFILE24m]...

1mDESCRIPTION0m
       Synchronize cached writes to persistent storage

       If one or more files are specified, sync only them, or their containing file systems.

       1m-d22m, 1m--data0m
```

As can be seen a `1m`, `22m`, `4m`, `24m` are used as (frustrating) highlighters.
I believe it is possibly 'end of line' or some other special characters. I am using Unicode UTF-8 encoding within the terminal preferences.

How can I get them removed?

Comment: For your example are you just running `man sync` or did you run something else? This looks like the `man` command is being forced to use terminal control characters while having its output sent to a pager. (Normally this wouldn't happen - `man` would drop the terminal formatting in this instance.)

Comment: Looks kind of similar to ansi escape codes used to add colours etc, eg have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code. I suspect shell or terminal misconfiguration. What does `env | grep TERM` show? Is there a matching terminal somewhere under `/usr/share/terminfo` or so?

Comment: Read `man man` `man -Tps` outputs as Postscript. You're outputting vt100 control sequences. `ESCape [ 1 m` is "Turn on bold font" for a terminal..

Comment: roaima  I am just running ' man sync ' in a terminal window.

Comment: cryptarch                                                                                                            $ env | grep TERM
TERM=xterm-256color
COLORTERM=truecolor

[me@PANTRY 2673 ~]

Comment: Those are (parts of) ANSI escape sequences. What if you type `-R` while reading the man page? (assuming this is `less` that is used as a pager)

Comment: `less` without `-R` would print the color codes as `ESC[...m` (with `ESC` inverted), but here, for some reason both the <ESC> and the `[` seem to be missing or hidden. Also at least on my systems, `man` doesn't even provide color codes to the pager, but backspaces for overstrike and underscore... (see `less -U`)

Comment: cryptarch  It essentially just bonks at me if I try to type -R while reading the man page. When I get out it gives a message. "Vim: Reading from stdin..."  I thought man used 'vi' not sure if that is relevant.  You indicate that a pager like 'less' is used.  I am not sure of that but it mentions 'vim'.  I have tried 'info' and it does not act this way.

Comment: One tip to get to a solution is check what's in $MANPAGER.

I had this problem; it turned out to be because when I installed batcat, I followed https://github.com/sharkdp/bat#man to set `export MANPAGER="sh -c 'col -bx | batcat -l man -p'"` in my .zshrc.  That same section recommends also setting `MANROFFOPT="-c"` which fixed this for me.

Comment: Also it's worth checking `LESS` and `LESSOPEN` environment variables, as well as `command -V less`.